# Compiling flex file into dll

Tags: dll, compilation, cygwin, flex-lexer

I've got a lexer created with flex (cygwin). Normally I compile it to an .exe file.

For the newest project I need a lexer to use in a bigger C# program running on Windows XP. Of course I can execute a file using System.Diagnostics.Process. But it is not the best solution for me as I want that program to run on several machines.

How can I create a dll under cygwin having the source code of the lexer?

Thanks in advance...
Szpilona

Answer (score 1):

Flex produces a C or C++ source file with a yylex() function.

Run flex on your grammar (.l file) to produce a .c or .cpp file, then compile that file with gcc -c to produce an object file, or compile it with gcc -shared to produce a .so library.

```
flex toy.l
gcc -shared toy.lexer.c
```

Flex or Flex++ will produce a lexer that can be compiled with or without cywgin. You can also use MinGW or Visual C++.

Comment: Well, I've already tried that. Precisely I ran flex on my grammar and then compiled the obtained c file with:

gcc -c lekser.c
gcc -shared -o lekser.dll lekser.o

dll file was created but it does not work. I've tried to access the library using the code:

        [DllImport("lekser.dll")]
        public static extern int yylex();

but the DllNotFoundException occured. The file, for sure, is placed in the right directory and the C# code is correct (at least it works with another dll I've created to test this). That's why I thought there was an option needed when running flex on grammar file.

Comment: Is the dll in your PATH? That exception is a "file found found" type of exception.